# Classifying polygons and weight them

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

Hi I have this dataset:

```
> head(sp_csv_data)
Longitude   Latitude Radius Site_Type
1 -177.87567 -24.715167     10       MIG
2  -83.21360  14.401800      1       OBS
3  -82.59392   9.589192      1       NES
4  -82.41060   9.492750      1   NES;BRE
5  -81.17555   7.196750      5       OBS
6  -80.95770   8.852700      1       NES
```

The longitude and latitude are the coordinates of center of the sites. The sites are circles and the radius column is the radius of the site. The final column is the site type.

I need to convert these .csv information into raster. I was able to plot the circles and to rasterize them. Now I need to classify them according to the site type. This is how the layer looks like so far:

```
> print(sp_robinson)
Simple feature collection with 46519 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -16675160 ymin: -5378567 xmax: 16655730 ymax: 6089138
CRS:            +proj=robin +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
First 10 features:
   layer                       geometry
1     69 POLYGON ((11889163 6089138,...
2     69 POLYGON ((11927764 6089138,...
3     69 POLYGON ((11966365 6089138,...
4     73 POLYGON ((12622585 6089138,...
5     73 POLYGON ((12661186 6089138,...
6     73 POLYGON ((12699787 6089138,...
7     73 POLYGON ((12738389 6089138,...
8     73 POLYGON ((12776990 6089138,...
9     73 POLYGON ((12815591 6089138,...
10    73 POLYGON ((12854192 6089138,...
```

[And this is how I was able to plot it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ciJf.png)

Any idea how should I proceed to classify the circles according to the site types?

This is the code I've used so far:

```
lon <- c(-177.87567, -83.2136, -82.59392, -82.4106, -81.17555, -80.9577)
lat <- c(-24.715167, 14.4018, 9.589192, 9.49275, 7.19675, 8.8527)
radius <- c(10, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1)
site <- c("MIG", "OBS", "NES", "NES;BRE", "OBS", "NES")
sp_csv_data <- data.frame(lon, lat, radius, site)

####Defining Datum and Coordinates system (best to do first to avoid errors later)
rob_pacific <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" 
longlat <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

####Creating the nodes####
    
nodes <- sp_csv_data %>%
  st_buffer(dist = sp_csv_data$Radius)

####Converting to raster####
 
# Creating a empty raster at 0.5° resolution (you can increase the resolution to get a better border precision)
rs <- raster(ncol = 360*2, nrow = 180*2) 
rs[] <- 1:ncell(rs)
crs(rs) <- CRS(longlat)

##Convering to raster
sp_raster <- rasterize(nodes, rs)

# Resampling to make sure that it's in the same resolution as sampling area
sp_raster <- resample(sp_raster, rs, resample = "ngb")

#converting into an sf spatial polygon dataframe
sp_raster <- as(sp_raster, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
species_sp <- spTransform(sp_raster, CRS(longlat))

# Define a long & slim polygon that overlaps the meridian line & set its CRS to match that of world
polygon <- st_polygon(x = list(rbind(c(-0.0001, 90),
                                     c(0, 90),
                                     c(0, -90),
                                     c(-0.0001, -90),
                                     c(-0.0001, 90)))) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_set_crs(longlat)

# Transform the species distribution polygon object to a Pacific-centred projection polygon object
sp_robinson <- species_sp %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_difference(polygon) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = rob_pacific)

# There is a line in the middle of Antarctica. This is because we have split the map after reprojection. We need to fix this:
bbox1 <-  st_bbox(sp_robinson)
bbox1[c(1,3)]  <-  c(-1e-5,1e-5)
polygon1 <- st_as_sfc(bbox1)
crosses1 <- sp_robinson %>%
  st_intersects(polygon1) %>%
  sapply(length) %>%
  as.logical %>%
  which
# Adding buffer 0
sp_robinson[crosses1, ] %<>%
  st_buffer(0)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I showed you how to make your example more reproducible. Please edit your question accordingly   https://stackoverflow.com/a/67113125/635245

Comment: Thank you for all of the help and advice! I really appreciate it, I'm very new to this... I hope this is much clearer and more reproducible!

Comment: What I want to say is that in my answer I show how to make your code reproducible, as you can copy and paste it and it runs. So if you start with that, you can also show where you get stuck. You are doing many things. My advice would be to first rasterize on a lon/lat raster. If you have that, the next thing would be to worry about the unusual crs you want to use.

Comment: Thanks! I understand better now! As you can see I was able to rasterize my circles and now all I need is to classify them! I see now that I was redoing a lot of useless steps but I think now it's more general and easier. Thanks again!